# Hibernate Caching Negative Hits

Tags: hibernate, spring, ehcache

I have two tables from two different departments:

**Customer**
ID
County
State
Name, Age, etc.

**Billing Rate**  (composite ID of County/State)
County
State
Price

In Hibernate, I have defined a @ManyToOne relationship on a composite foreign key (county/state).  I followed this:
[Hibernate Annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177%20Hibernate%20Annotations)

Well, Every Customer has a county/state, but not every county-state pair is represented in the billing table.  When I load some of the Customer entities, I get an exception of EntityNotFoundException for the relationship.  Based on my reading here (same problem as me): [JBoss Forums](http://community.jboss.org/message/522967) It looks like every relationship NEEDS to be there, although you can slap on a @NotFound(action=IGNORE) tag.  Well, I did that too and it works without error, but I'm still having a problem.  Hibernate does not cache the negative-hits, so if a county/state pair is NOT found, the exception is ignored, but the knowledge of that "lack of data" is not cached, so it re-loads the relationship on demand, every time.  So, when I do a left join fetch on the relationship, it effectively does nothing for me.  Also, a batch-fetch does nothing, I have to load them one at a time, and I'm talking about thousands of entities.

What can I do to resolve this?  Is the DB designed wrong???  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Hibernate second-level (are you assuming it?) cache doesn't support caching of objects with composite identifiers.